# Async def vs def in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

Can someone explain to me why FastAPI recommends not to use `async def` in blocking I/O operations in detail?
I've searched online but couldn't find a single explanation that had all the details.

Answer (score 0):

quoting [python-doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#running-blocking-code)

Blocking (CPU-bound) code should not be called directly. For example, if a function performs a CPU-intensive calculation for 1 second, all concurrent asyncio Tasks and IO operations would be delayed by 1 second.